# How to use the returned value of a Python Function when using a PythonOperator on Airflow/

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am build an airflow DAG with multiple PythonOperator nodes. One of them returns a value that will later be used as a param of another operator. But how can I store and access this returned value?

For example:
I have the following functions

```
def sum(a, b):
    return a + b

def compare(c, d):
   return c > d
```

And the following dag:

```
sum = PythonOperator(
      task_id = 'sum',
      python_callable = sum,
      op_args = [a, b],
      dag = dag
      )

compare = PythonOperator(
     task_id = 'compare',
     python_callable = compare,
     op_args = [{VALUE}, c]
     dag = dag
     )

sum >> compare
```

I want {VALUE} to be the value returned when the sum node is executed. How can I store and access it?

Comment: you can try to share results via XCOMs https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to share state or results via [XCOMs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=xcom):

```
def sum(a, b, **context):
    result = a + b 
    context['task_instance'].xcom_push(key='result_of_sum', value=result)

def compare(c, d, **context):
   result_of_sum = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(key='result_of_sum')
   return c > d
```

please don't forget to `provide_context=True` to PythonOperator parameters